# GWT rpc callback does not call after calling in GWTTestCase

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, servlets, gwttestcase

I have written a GWTTestCase like this:

```
public void testClickButton() {
    SampleView view = new SampleView();
    RootPanel.get().add(view);
    view.textBox.setText("Saeed Zarinfam");

    assertEquals("", view.label.getText());

//        ButtonElement.as(view.button.getElement()).click();
    view.button.getElement().<ButtonElement>cast().click();

    assertEquals("Bean \"OCTO\" has been created", view.label.getText());
}
```

When i run this test it connect to my servlet (i added some log on my servlet) but the RPC callback does not call in my `SampleView`, junit say:

```
expected: <Bean "OCTO" has been created>, actual: <>
```

This is my callback in button click handler:

```
@UiHandler("button")
void onClick(ClickEvent e) {

    labelTest.setText("click button");

    AsyncCallback<FooBean> callback = new AsyncCallback<FooBean>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // Show the RPC error message to the user
            labelTest.setText("call fail");
            label.setText("Failure : " + caught.getMessage());
        }

        public void onSuccess(FooBean result) {
            labelTest.setText("call success");
            label.setText("Bean \"" + result.getName() + "\" has been created");
        }
    };

    // Make the call. Control flow will continue immediately and later
    // 'callback' will be invoked when the RPC completes.
    service.createBean("OCTO", callback);


}
```

Why GWT rpc callback does not call in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPC calls are asynchronous even in `GWTTestCase`. You have to call `delayTestFinish()` to tell the runner that the test is asynchronous, and call `finish()` "at some point in the future" to tell it it's finished and OK (otherwise you'll have a timeout).

In your case, because the calling code has no way to know when the RPC call is finished, you can only do a wild guess at how many time it'll take, and use `Timer`.
Better refactor your code to make it more testable if you ask me (note: a Selenium would work roughly the same: check a condition every second until a timeout, http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#the-waitfor-commands-in-ajax-applications, just like a `Timer` that you'd re-schedule up to N times if the condition is not met)

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting#DevGuideAsynchronousTesting

Comment: T hank's Thomas, I have a question, I have tested gwt-test-utils lib for my case, it was working with gwt rpc nice but my GWT ui is complicated and it could not parse my *.ui.xml files and then i select GWTTestCase, Do i select the right way?

Comment: I find gwt-test-utils way too hackish. For end-to-end tests, I think I'd rather go the Selenium (or similar) way, and use GWTTestCase only/mostly for unit tests (of widgets or other JSNI-based things). But actually, I'm rather bad at testing apps (much better at testing libs/APIs).